# Should I do loss masking while using variable sequence length in Dynamic_RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, text-classification, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently building a model for text classification using Dynamic RNN in tf. My inputs are of different lengths, so I padded the inputs to be of same (max) length.

I used the sequence_length argument in tf.nn.dynamic_rnn to feed in a list of each input length.

My question:

Should I do loss masking? and When to do loss masking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you need not do loss masking. I assume you want a fixed length vector output for each sequence. Since you are giving the sequence length as input, dynamic RNN automatically makes sure that the state is copied through for the sequence outside the sequence length.

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn. Look at the information about the sequence_length argument.

Comment: If you are passing sequence_length list, then inside the Rnn loop, tensorflow copies the last state through the <pad> computations. You still have to pad the sequences with zeros even if you send sequence lengths. No need to do loss masking.

Comment: I have tried that by myself, printed both the states and outputs, and turns out that I don’t need to do loss masking, Thank you :)